# Is immutability useful on non parallel applications?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, immutability

I like the immutability concept but sometimes I wonder, when an application isn't meant to be parallel, should one avoid making things immutable?

When an application isn't multi-threaded, you aren't plagued by shared state problems, right?

Or is immutability a concept like OOP that you either use all the way or not? Excluding the cases when something shouldn't be immutable based on use/performance, etc.

I am faced with this question when writing an application for myself, that is moderately big (maybe like 1-2k lines).

Comment: Immutable state is good for multithreaded applications because it is easier to reason about the correctness of immutable state in multithreaded scenarios. But it is ALSO easier to reason about correctness of immutable state in single-threaded scenarios! It is just plain easier to reason about things that do not change than it is to reason about things that do change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I love immutability because it means I don't have to trust other peoples code not to mess around with objects I expect to stay the same.

When you pass an object off to another component such as a `List<T>`, you are at the mercy of what that component does.  This is especially important when you return collections as properties.

```
public class Foo { 
  private List<Bar> _barList;
  public ICollection<Bar> BarList { get return _barList; } 
}
```

There's nothing stopping a consumer of this class from clearing the collection out from under me.  Even switching the return type to `IEnumerable<Bar>` is not entirely safe.  There's nothing stopping some piece of badly written code from casting this back to `List<T>` and calling .Clear().

However if I really want the collection to stay consistent I could rewrite it as followis

```
public class Foo {
  private ImmutableCollection<Bar> _barList;
  public ImmutableCollection<Bar> BarList { get { return _barList; } }
}
```

Now I'm safe from having to trust other code from using my class incorrectly.  They can't mess it up.

Comment: Is ImmutableCollection in BCL? Or just an example?

Comment: @Joan, it's from a library that I own.  It's available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BclExtras

Comment: Thanks Jared, will download it.

Comment: You could also return List<T>.AsReadOnly(), which is built into the BCL.

Comment: @Joe, Unfortunately ReadOnly collection is not immutable, it is merely read only.  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/04/22/api-design-readonlycollection-t.aspx

Comment: @Joan, there's ReadOnlyCollection<T> in the framework if you don't want to roll your own. If when you construct it you throw away the List<T> you used to construct it, it will be immutable since there won't be any references around to the writeable internals of it. I agree with Jared that this can be a "gotcha" if you aren't on the look-out, though, and encapsulating this "create and throw away the List<T>" business could be useful.

Comment: @JaredPar, if the collection is immutable, is `Foo` replacing it in certain scenarios? In other words, what happens when you need internal mutability but external immutability.

Answer (score 9):

I like the advantage from immutability that you need to validate it only once - at creation of object. That's a huge bonus actually.

Comment: Good point. This idea also has security implications. Suppose you pass a mutable object X to method Foo. Foo checks X to ensure that X is a valid argument to Foo, throws if it is not, and then makes some security-sensitive operation based on X. If a hostile caller can mutate X on another thread after the argument check, the argument check can effectively be bypassed! This is one reason why strings are immutable in .NET -- you want to be able to say "open this file", do a security check on that path, and know that the path string will not change between the check and the file open.

Comment: To do this, one is to use static factory pattern ... synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

A major benefit of immutability is that one need not track ownership of immutable objects.  They just exist as long as anybody needs them, and then vanish into nothingness when they are no longer required.  While using a garbage-collector in many cases means it's not necessary to write any expressly code dealing with ownership of mutable objects (the biggest exception being those that implement `IDisposable`), in many cases it's very difficult to write correct code in which objects that have mutable state do not have one clearly-defined "owner".  Confusion about who owns the state of mutable objects can be a very frequent source of bugs; when using immutable objects (aside from a few that implement `IDisposable`) one can generally ignore ownership issues.

Another point to consider is that it is far easier to reason about a mutable reference to a semantically-immutable object, or an immutable reference to a mutable object, than it is to reason about a mutable reference to a mutable object.  If one has a mutable reference to a mutable objects, it can often be unclear whether the correct approach to updating state is to simply mutate the object directly, or copy its state to a new object, mutate that, and update the reference.  In some cases, there will be circumstances requiring each type of operation (as with `List<T>`, which sometimes replaces an array with a bigger one, but usually does updates in-place), but such an approach only works if the type maintains exclusive control over the mutable objects in question.  It's often more helpful to either have an immutable reference to a mutable type (in which case code may expose the reference, possibly through a read-only wrapper, to other objects which want a "live view" of its state) or else have a mutable reference to an object which is immutable or, at minimum, will never be mutated during the lifetime of the reference.